# webpack require expression missing modules

Tags: node.js, webpack

From [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-with-expression), when a require expression is not known at compile time, it should generate a context module and include all the modules that could match the expression.

```
const handlers = {};

for (const name of Object.keys(SomeObject)) {
  try {
    handlers[name] = require(`./${name}.js`);
  } catch {} // eslint-disable-line no-empty
}

module.exports = handlers;
```

however, what I get is `

```
const handlers = {};

for (const name of Object.keys(SomeObject)) {
  try {
    handlers[name] = require(`./${name}.js`);
  } catch {} // eslint-disable-line no-empty
}

module.exports = handlers;
```

however, what I actually get is this error `Cannot find module ./\u001a.js`

but if I turn it into a dynamic import expression then it works

```
const handlers = {};

for (const name of Object.keys(SomeObject)) {
  try {
    import(`./${name}.js`).then(m => { handler[name] = m; });
  } catch {} // eslint-disable-line no-empty
}

module.exports = handlers;
```

But I would prefer not to do that since the offending code is from some node package